# Mojolicious one liner to service status files with listing directory

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I am looking for Mojolicious one liner for serving static files and listing the directory by default

I come to this one liner :

```
perl -Mojo -E "a->static->paths(['c:\temp']);a->start" daemon
```

which serving static files on specific directory but its not listing the files by default , any idea if it can be changed to also list the files by default as one liner ?

Answer (score 6):

Not a Mojo solution, but still Perl. You can use [`http_this`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-HTTPThis/bin/http_this) to achieve the same thing. See the App::HTTPThis package.

```
$ http_this
Exporting '.', available at:
   http://127.0.0.1:7007/
```

There are also some other packages that do [https](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-HTTPSThis/script/https_this), [run CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-CGIThis/bin/cgi_this), [serve files on an FTP server](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-FTPThis/script/ftp_this) or even [share them over WebDAV](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-DAVThis/script/dav_this).